# How to add a custom line to navigation bar in CSS

Tags: html, css

currently trying to add a cool design line like

> http://forrester-park.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Fancy-line.png

to the bottom of my custom navigation bar. How would add something like that? Is there a to add it into the css of the navigation bar rather than pulling it in as an image? Something like http://jsfiddle.net/henry12345/6h3Lee0e/

mainly here:

```
width:auto
border-top:1 px solid #000000;
border-radius:3px;
```

Comment: you can just get the F12 on that site and check out the styles applied else you need to create jsfiddle or working demo code

Comment: @Himesh Doesn't seem like that would be implementing directly into my navigation bar. It's just an image, not coded

Comment: You can create a line with CSS (this is easy) and then you need image for the small curly thing - this you have two options: using img directly (as e.g. `background-image` or you can use iconfont. I recommend page https://icomoon.io/ - free library with many icons, or you can create your own

Comment: You can also convert images to css

Comment: @areim could I do like border-bottom: url("something.com")

Comment: there is also property called `border-image`, see support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image

Comment: You cannot use a resource as border, but you can use a background that should come after your navigation section, using the `:after`-selector: `navigation:after {background: url("your_image");}`

Comment: @areim seems to only apply to the whole border?

Comment: @NewBeginnings hm... I'm looking on it and you are right - it is only for whole border :( sorry, this does not solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like

```
background:url('image_url');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom center;
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin:  10px 0px  10px 0px;
```

or use border image(http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image IE could be an isssue), if you could provide your html/stles in fiddle - can suggest a solution

Comment: added jsfiddle link but this code just makes my navigational bar higher

Answer (score 0):

Try a combo of horizontal rule and font-awesome. Change the icon in the middle to whatever you want.

```css
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    margin:18px 0;
    position:relative;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 10%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 90%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(10%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(90%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 10%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 10%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 10%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 10%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    margin-top: 60px;
}

hr:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: solid 1px #f9f9f9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}

hr:after { 
    content: "\f1ce";
    position: absolute;
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -8px;
    left: 48%;
    z-index: 99999999;
    background-color: white;
    color: #666;
    
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

## `<div>` with :after property

I don't know how your navigation bar looks like, but you can get the desired effect by adding an `:after` property to your menu `<div>`.

Here an example using your image:

```css
.menu {
    position: relative;
}

.menu:after {
    content: url(http://forrester-park.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Fancy-line.png);
    display: block;
    background: white;

    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"> 
    <h1>Some Title</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Menu item 1</li>
    <li>Menu item 2</li>
    <li>Menu item 3</li>
    <li>Menu item 4</li>
</ul>    
 </div>
```

[jsfiddle with the same content to play around](https://jsfiddle.net/ysuter/ebfbr1x2/)

Comment: great, but the image doesn't resize with my border.

Comment: Do you want to scale the image as a whole or e.g. just expand the length of the lines on the side of the image? If so, the solutions using `<hr>` may be more suitable.

Comment: I want it to go with the top navigation bar